# Pygame for python 3.5?

Tags: python, pygame

I just got Python 3.5 from [this link](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/).

Previously I had Python 3.4 and the Pygame version 1.9.2a0. It worked perfectly. However, my the new Python 3.5 isn't compatible with that version of Pygame that I had gotn for the 3.4. I Found the latest Pygame file from [this link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame).

I downloaded the Pygame file, however, it is a .whl format file. What am I supposed to do?

I have tried looking it up all day yesterday. So far all I've figured out is something about pip and wheel and doing some commands like 'pip install' etc. etc. But I am completely lost. I never knew about pip or any of that before.

I am not even sure if there is a version of Pygame that works with Python 3.5, but I did try to find out by looking it up but I never found such information.

All I want is to get Python 3.5 up and running with Pygame and for it to work just as fine as it used to when I had Python 3.4. If Pygame is yet to be compatible with Python 3.5 that's fine, I'll just reinstall python 3.4 and the according Pygame file for it.

Answer (score 6):

This site showed me how to do it: https://skellykiernan.wordpress.com/2015/01/04/python-pygame-install/

Note that the site uses Python 3.4.2 and pygame version 34cp, but I did it with Python 3.5 and pygame version 35cp and it worked perfectly.

Comment: You can find the whl files here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame

Comment: figured out an even easier solution.  I used pip.  It installed the right version for the right python Im using (3.5) and took 7 seconds in total.  Far different from the manual installation process of everything else.